# Changing WPA supplicant configuration on dd-wrt

Tags: router, dd-wrt, wpa2-psk, wpa-supplicant

I installed dd-wrt on my Fonera (old model), and I'm trying to use it as an ethernet-wlan adapter for a PC without WiFi (using it in client-mode).

I've configured everything following a step-by-step tutorial, and it didn't work. After that I entered with ssh, and found the configuration file (in /tmp).

If I change the wpa_supplicant configuration (remove most lines, leave only the SSID and WPA-PSK), it works. The "wrong" configuration seems to be the first line of the configuration file: "ap_scan=2".

The problem is: when I reboot it, it reads the old configuration, and I have to ssh again, and change the temporary configuration.

So, what I'm trying to do now (without success so far) is one of the three:

- change the non-volatile configuration, and make it persistent.
- find a way to configure WPA2 security in the web interface without writing extra lines in the config file
- use some kind of script on system start (after everything else), which kills wpa_supplicant, writes the right config file, and starts it again.

I can't write to /etc because it's read-only, and I can't simply remount it read-write. I've read something about enabilng JFFS but I couldn't really understand how it works.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply put your script in **Administration** → **Commands** → **Save Startup Scripts**